# Use "bridge" as an intransitive verb?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, verb-usage

I found the following sentence:

> The system controller interfaces to the PCI bus and **bridges to** other buses.

I can guess the meaning of it, but looking at all the dictionary the verb "bridge" does not have any usages as an intransitive verb.

Is it grammatically correct to use the verb "bridge" like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I understand your question, but in the example you are giving, "to bridge" is used (correctly) as a _transitive_ verb ("other buses" being the object). So I find myself confused as to what you are actually asking.

Comment: Technical documentation is not the best place to audit for grammar because you are bound to find non-standard uses of language that would not be used in another context.  That being said, one of the definitions of the word `bridge` is a verb that means "to make a bridge (over)".  Another example of this used in a sentence: "The new causeway bridges the span between the mainland and Oak Island"

Comment: This question is based on the faulty premise that *bridge* is being used intransitively. It's not. It's being used [*transitively*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bridge#h2).